# New built PC won't boot - is a part dead?

Tags: computer-building, post

I bought a Biostar TA-970 plus motherboard, an AMD FX-8350 CPU, 2x8DDR3 1600 RAM blocks, an EVGA Geforce GT740 graphics adapter. When I power on it all seems to run (fans, lights) and no error beeps, but nothing appears on screen. There isn't a lot on config-options (jumpers etc) on the motherboard, so shouldn't it just work or at least give an error? Pointers anyone?

Answer (score -1):

If it doesn't POST at all (beep at you when you turn it on), I would make sure the ram isn't only partially seated. Try each stick seperately in case you got a bad stick. Make sure the cpu is properly seated so it is makeing contact everywhere that it should. And that your PSU isn't underpowered.

There is a similar thread that might be helpful at:
[Why won't my computer boot (first time)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1107923/why-wont-my-computer-boot-first-time/1107977#1107977)